how to solve a quadratic equation in two variables of the form $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey + f$?
Given
$ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey + f = 0$
How would one go about solving such an equation, is it possible to solve for both $x$ and $y$ or will we end up with an equation for them?

Do you expect this to have a unique solution? Consider the example: $x^2+y^2-1=0,.$

@KurtG. What about this $x^2+y^2=0$

You just write $y^2 + \left( \frac{e}{c} + \frac{b}{c}x \right) y + \left( \frac{a}{c}x^2+\frac{d}{c}x+\frac{f}{c} \right)$ and then complete the square with respect to $y$. This gives an equation for $y$ in terms of $x$. Your equation is just the equation for conic sections: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad what about $x^2+y^2=-1,?$

@KurtG. Hehehe.

Let's define $p(x, y) = ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f.$
Reminding that the equation given is quadratic for $x$ and $y$ each, let's focus on 1 variable.
$p(x, y) = ax^2+(by+d)x+(cy^2+ey+f).$
Let's think about the equation $p(x, y)=0$, then the solution for $x$ is the following:
$$x = \dfrac{-by-d\pm\sqrt{(b^2-4ac)y^2+(2bd-4ae)y+d^2-4af}}{2a}.$$
It means that:
$$p(x, y) \\ \small = a\left(x+\dfrac{by+d+\sqrt{(b^2-4ac)y^2+(2bd-4ae)y+d^2-4af}}{2a}\right)\left(x+\dfrac{by+d-\sqrt{(b^2-4ac)y^2+(2bd-4ae)y+d^2-4af}}{2a}\right)$$
...and I think this is our best(or worst) result.

p.s. The quadratic equation forms a conic section, which is well-known.

It depends on what you mean by solution! The most general remark is that, given any function $F(x,y)$ defined on the plane, one has a set of pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation $F(x,y)=0$. This is more abstract than what you are looking for. But qualitative statements about the solutions may be interesting in their own right; people have already pointed out that the solution of your family of equations is called a conic section, and they are, to say the least, well-studied.
Typically (though not always) such an equation has a curve as its solution set. The problem of solving the equation then involves a way of describing the solution. You may want a parametric solution of some kind, and there is a choice in what you take to be your parameter.
RDK has given you an answer where the parameter is just $y$. Geometrically you may consider a horizontal line $y=c$ free to move vertically. It will intersect the curve at possibly 0, 1, or 2 points, because the resulting equation involving $x$ is at most quadratic. You will have, generally, two parametric partial solutions, and the solution at some times may be imaginary, for e.g. $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$.
One can find real solutions of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in a slightly more satisfactory way. Its solution set is (perhaps by definition) the unit circle. Consider the line through $(-1,0)$ with slope $-\infty < t < \infty$. It intersects the unit circle at precisely two points. We know the first, and the second $(x,y)$ may be determined as follows. Squaring the slope gives $t^2 = y^2 / (x+1)^2 = (1-x)/(1+x)$, and this quantity is its own inverse as a function of $x$ (a so-called involution). Hence $x = (1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$, and solving for $y$ using the slope gives $y=2t/(1+t^2)$. This parametric solution is a curve running between the angles $-\pi < \theta < \pi$ on the unit circle, and gives all but one solution. (This is also a method for finding Pythagorean triples!)
You can extend this method of solution to more general situations, but the best choice of parameter will depend on the nature of the curve. I don't believe there is any nice general formula which will provide a single-valued parametric solution.
